# ArXiv and Hbbrv in Google Scholar

Tags: bibtex, arxiv, google-scholar

When using

\bibliographystyle{habbrv}

and citing a paper from arXiv (using the bibtex citation provided by arXiv), the paper appears as:

Author. Title, Year, YYMM.XXXXX.

It does not show the arXiv prefix.
Is this an issue for google scholar to detect the citation?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I in general *trust* google for parsing the author names and the title. Also, if the YYMM.XXXXX is actually a hyperlink, there is no way google will miss that.

Comment: I suspect that it depends on how google is doing their reference extraction. Sometimes formatting can be an issue (e.g. if the ids are set in a monospaced font or italics block and they're reading the raw source it could be missing the links while parsing). This is a problem in some instances with hyperref and arXiv's auto-linking to arXiv-ids, for example.